# Unable to sum values from a collection in a foreach loop

Tags: javascript

My wish is that the entire sum is calculated and then divided by the iterations, to create an average temperature, that I can display.

I have tried the reduce* method, but it won't work together with observation.temperature, which I use to get the temperature value.

```
async function updateObservationList() {
    const url = "/api/get-all-observations";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();

    const tableBody = document.getElementById("table-body");
    const averageTemperature = document.getElementById("averageTemperature");

    const selector = document.getElementById("stationSelector").value;

    let sum = 0;
    let iteration = 0;

    removeElements();

    data.forEach(observation => {
        if(selector == 0) {

            /**
             * Sums temperature of all selected observations and divides it by the number of iterations,
             * thereby getting the average temperature
             */

            sum += observation.temperature;
            iteration++;
            console.log(sum)
            console.log(iteration)

            averageTemperature.textContent = (sum /= iteration).toString();
```

[image]
[image: Result]
This is what happens in the console.

I get this result.

[image]

consol.log(data)
[image]

console.log(data)
[image]

console.log(observation)

Comment: *I have tried the reduce method, but it won't work together with observation.temperature* Ok then you should add code

Comment: Thank you for commenting! What do you mean? Do you want me to write out the non working reduce method?

Comment: You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that everyone can understand it properly. Without sufficient information, no one can help you...

Comment: Yeah you are right, unfortunately the total function is 229 lines long, so I didn't want to confuse

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to recreate the scene, and your code works fine.

```js
const selector = document.getElementById("stationSelector").value;
const averageTemperature = document.getElementById("averageTemperature");
let sum = 0;
let iteration = 0;

data = [{
  temperature: 27
}, {
  temperature: 32
}, {
  temperature: 25
}, {
  temperature: 28
}, {
  temperature: 22
}, {
  temperature: 21
}]


data.forEach(observation => {
  if (selector == 0) {
    /**
     * Sums temperature of all selected observations and divides it by the number of iterations,
     * thereby getting the average temperature
     */

    sum += observation.temperature;
    iteration++;
  }
})
averageTemperature.textContent = (sum /= iteration).toString();
```

```html
<input type="number" value="0" id="stationSelector">
<p id="averageTemperature"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking a swing at it! - Hmm, then something else must be wrong, I've updated the post with my result picture.

Comment: Should I post the whole function? It's 229 lines long, so I'm afraid that it's more confusing than good

Comment: @FrederikMeiznerPetersen Can you post the `console.log` of data?

Comment: Sure, just a sec, thank you for helping me!